# Android - ListView multiple choice only selecting 2 items

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Anybody know why `i'm only able to select 2 items` after activating my `ListView` to `Multiple Choice`.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Activate CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
                multipleActivated = true;
                listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                Log.w("Multiple Selection", "Activated");
                return true;
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (multipleActivated == false) {
                   //Perform normal click and call new intent
                   .....
                } else {
                   //set the clicked item to be checked since the Multiple Selection is activated
                    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    Log.w("Selection", String.valueOf(position));
                }
            }
        });
```

As you can see in my code, i only want to activate the `Multiple Choice Mode` once the LongPress is perform, this ok and working fine but im oly able to select 2 items, on the 3rd selection the first selected item just deselecting. i don't know why. anybody can help me here? Thank You!

Comment: Check what a sparse boolean array is and how you can use that to remember the state of your checkboxes using one.

Comment: I think this topic is hopeful for you:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/

Comment: http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html use this tutorial